# Remove common elements of hostnames (shorten hostnames) - DRY

Tags: python, python-2.7, dry

**Explanation:**

I wrote the following function to shorten the hostnames of machines used in production. The names have been changed here, but the same structure and format has been preserved. The code below is clunky, and I would like to make the code [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Readability is also important, as this is code that might need to be maintained or understood by more than just myself.

**Code:**

```
def shorten_hostnames(machines):
    # split items
    d = {k: v.split('.') for k, v in machines.items()}
    # trim end
    while all(d.values()):
        if not len(set([v[-1] for v in d.values()])) == 1:
            break
        if not all(len(v) > 1 for v in d.values()):
            break
        d = {k: v[:-1] for k, v in d.items()}
    # trim start
    while all(d.values()):
        if not len(set([v[0] for v in d.values()])) == 1:
            break
        if not all(len(v) > 1 for v in d.values()):
            break            
        d = {k: v[1:] for k, v in d.items()}
    # join items
    d = {k: '.'.join(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    # return shortened hostnames
    return d
```

**Sample Input:**

```
machines = {'a.ace.site.info': 'a.ace.site.info',
            'b.ace.site.info': 'b.ace.site.info',
            'a.bob.site.info': 'a.bob.site.info',
            'b.bob.site.info': 'b.bob.site.info',}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> for k, v in shorten_hostnames(machines).items():
    print k, '-->', v

b.ace.site.info --> b.ace
a.ace.site.info --> a.ace
b.bob.site.info --> b.bob
a.bob.site.info --> a.bob
```

**Where and why I need *your* help:**

I was trying to embed a function that would do the trimming from either end based on supplied parameters, but I can't figure out how to modify the slice notation to trim from either the start or the end of the list. I am sure there is a simple solution I am overlooking, either with slice notation or something else.

**Gotcha's:**

There are a few things that need to be mentioned here that are what you would call a "Gotcha". If only one hostname is passed into the function, (example `machines = {'a.ace.site.info': 'a.ace.site.info'}`) it should return only the first part (in the example `a`). Also - there should be no duplicate results in the final answer. Also - the hostnames can have different lengths from each other (not the same amount of segments)

**Afterthought:**

Once a proper solution can be found, I will edit the question title and tags to better reflect how this can apply to future visitors of the site. For instance, if slice notation is the solution (and it can be applied dynamically) I would probably modify the question to reflect that dynamic slice notation is the topic of the question.

**More Sample Input and Expected Ouput:**

```
# In
machines = {'ace.a.site.info': 'ace.a.site.info',
            'ace.b.site.info': 'ace.b.site.info',}
# Out
ace.b.site.info --> b
ace.a.site.info --> a

# In
machines = {'a.ace.site.info': 'a.ace.site.info',}
# Out
a.ace.site.info --> a

# In
machines = {'ace.a.site.info': 'ace.a.site.info',
            'ace.b.site.com': 'ace.b.site.com',}
# Out
ace.b.site.com --> b.site.com
ace.a.site.info --> a.site.info
```

Comment: You mean you want to remove common prefixes and postfixes from a list of strings?

Comment: BTW that example code of yours seem to produce a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup. Thats what I understand from the example...

Comment: @MartijnPieters try this, this ought to reproduce it http://pastebin.com/Lr9QZFxn

Comment: Are all hostnames of equal length; e.g. do they all have the same number of dots in them?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No - they could have different lengths.

Comment: @InbarRose Can there be machines like this? `a.ace.site` and `a.ace.site.info`?

Comment: @thefourtheye That is a feasibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the very least, split out the values and keys into separate lists, then process just the values before reconstituting your dictionary, and use a short loop to pick an index for start and end trimming:

```
def shorten_hostnames(machines):
    keys, values = zip(*machines.items())
    values = [v.split('.') for v in values]
    for i, s in ((-1, slice(-1)), (0, slice(1, None))):
        while all(values):
            if not len(set(v[i] for v in values)) == 1:
                break
            if any(len(v) <= 1 for v in values):
                break
            values = [v[s] for v in values]
    return {k: '.'.join(v) for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
```

I'd use a utility function to remove a common prefix from a sequence of sequences, then pass in reversed sequences to remove trailing parts:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, izip_longest

def remove_common_prefix(*parts):
    # always leaves a last common element in place
    zipped = izip_longest(*(p[:-1] for p in parts), fillvalue=None)
    stripped = dropwhile(lambda v: len(set(v)) == 1, zipped)
    res = [filter(None, part) + (old[-1],) for part, old in zip(zip(*stripped), parts)]
    # filtered everything away? Then return just the last parts
    return res or [p[-1:] for p in parts]

def shorten_hostnames(machines):
    # edge-case; faster to just return the first part
    if len(machines) == 1:
        return {k: v.split('.', 1)[0] for k, v in machines.items()}
    keys, values = zip(*machines.items())  # for easier processing and re-assembling
    parts = remove_common_prefix(*(v.split('.')[::-1] for v in values))
    parts = remove_common_prefix(*(part[::-1] for part in parts))
    return {k: '.'.join(v) for k, v in zip(keys, parts)}
```

This handles both your input and names of uneven length:

```
>>> shorten_hostnames(machines)
{'b.ace.site.info': 'b.ace', 'a.ace.site.info': 'a.ace', 'b.bob.site.info': 'b.bob', 'a.bob.site.info': 'a.bob'}
>>> shorten_hostnames({'foo': 'a.ace.site', 'bar': 'a.ace.site.info'})
{'foo': 'site', 'bar': 'site.info'}
>>> shorten_hostnames({'ace.a.site.info': 'ace.a.site.info', 'ace.b.site.info': 'ace.b.site.info'})
{'ace.b.site.info': 'b', 'ace.a.site.info': 'a'}
>>> shorten_hostnames({'ace.a.site.info': 'ace.a.site.info'})
{'ace.a.site.info': 'ace'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def shorten_hostnames(machines):
    def trim(hostnames, head=True):
        while all(len(v) > 1 for v in hostnames) and len(set(v[0 if head else -1] for v in hostnames)) == 1:
            hostnames[:] = [v[1:] if head else v[:-1] for v in hostnames]

    keys, values = zip(*machines.items())
    hostnames = [v.split('.') for v in values]
    trim(hostnames, False)
    trim(hostnames)
    return {k: '.'.join(v) for k, v in zip(keys, hostnames)}
```

Comment: @InbarRose Can you please check my solution now?